# How to crash/disable/remove bluez interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, crash, d-bus, testing

I am building a bluetooth client for a project and I am looking for a way to crash the dbus bluetooth service offered by bluez, in Linux, prefferably in a controlled, recoverable manner.

Do you have any suggestions?

I only found ways to power off the bluetooth using

```
sudo service bluetooth stop
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

Source: https://di-marco.net/blog/it/2020-04-18-tips-disabling_bluetooth_on_raspberry_pi/